# I need to do web scraping to googlenews to get the link for different articles from different newspaper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to do web scraping to googlenews to get the link for different articles from different newspaper and I have a code that works pretty fine for today news (from googlenews). However it doesn't work for older articles. For example this code works to get different article links from google news:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from newspaper import Article
import random
import pandas as pd

root = 'https://www.google.com/'
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#

link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=revuelta+la+tercera&rlz=1C1UEAD_esCL995CL995&biw=1536&bih=714&tbm=nws&ei=qEWUYorfOuiy5OUP-aGLgA4&ved=0ahUKEwiK07Wfr4b4AhVoGbkGHfnQAuAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=revuelta+la+tercera&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LW5ld3MQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToFCAAQgAQ6CAgAEIAEELEDOggIABCxAxCDAToKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoECAAQQzoECAAQCjoGCAAQHhAWOggIABAeEA8QFlDIEliUnwFg1aABaAVwAHgAgAGSAYgBuw-SAQQyMS4ymAEAoAEBsAEAwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-news'
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

req = Request(link, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#

requests.get(link, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

webpage = urlopen(req).read()
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

with requests.Session() as c:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')
    for item in soup.find_all('div', attrs= {'class': 'ZINbbc luh4tb xpd O9g5cc uUPGi'}):
        raw_link = item.find('a', href=True)['href']

        link = raw_link.split('/url?q=')[1].split('&sa=U&')[0]

        article = Article(link, language = "es")
        
        article.download()
        
        article.parse()
        
        title = article.title
        
        descript = article.text
        
        date = article.publish_date
        
        print(title)
        print(descript)
        print(link)
```

Now I need to change the dates for the same search, so I just change the link with the custom interval:

```
root = 'https://www.google.com/'
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#

link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=revuelta+la+tercera&rlz=1C1UEAD_esCL995CL995&biw=1536&bih=714&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2018%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F6%2F2018&tbm=nws'
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

req = Request(link, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3)) #----------stop---------#

requests.get(link, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

webpage = urlopen(req).read()
time.sleep(random.randint(0, 6)) #----------stop---------#

with requests.Session() as c:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')
    for item in soup.find_all('div', attrs= {'class': 'ZINbbc luh4tb xpd O9g5cc uUPGi'}):
        raw_link = item.find('a', href=True)['href']

        link = raw_link.split('/url?q=')[1].split('&sa=U&')[0]

        article = Article(link, language = "es")
        
        article.download()
        
        article.parse()
        
        title = article.title
        
        descript = article.text
        
        date = article.publish_date
        
        print(title)
        print(descript)
        print(link)
```

The links are supposed to be different (due to the change of search dates) but they both give me the same result and I don't understand why. Please help guys, I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the URL you provided is

> https://www.google.com/search?q=revuelta+la+tercera&rlz=1C1UEAD_esCL995CL995&biw=1536&bih=714&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2018%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F6%2F2018&tbm=nws

If you read it carefully **cd_min** and **cd_max** seems to include datetime data.

> cd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2018%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F6%2F2018

So let's slice them from URL. String above is sliced from the URL and it is URL encoded. If you decode it you will see..

> cd_min:1/1/2018,cd_max:1/6/2018

So If you want to change date for your query, you should make change to URL.

```py
from urllib import parse

# URL ENCODE
# DON'T FORGET : and , 
start_date = parse.quote_plus(":1/1/2018,")
end_date = parse.quote_plus(":1/6/2018")

# CREATE QUERY
link = f"https://www.google.com/search?q=revuelta+la+tercera&rlz=1C1UEAD_esCL995CL995&biw=1536&bih=714&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min{start_date}cd_max{end_date}&tbm=nws"
```

The code to randomize date is your job :)

Comment: sorry but I get the following error: "not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object". Probably is a really basic question but it's my first time doing web scrapping. Normaly I worked only with pandas and numpy. Thank so much I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: @CristobalPerez Sorry my mistake. You should use parse.quote_plus() not parse.urlencode()